# Find out if an function argument is part of a function call

Tags: objective-c

Ok, I think it is next to impossible. But nevertheless: Is it possible to know inside a method call if the method was called as part of a function call?

Example (and my actual function call):

```
HDMExpressionSQLSelectBuilder *sb = [[[HDMExpressionSQLSelectBuilder alloc] init] autorelease];
[sb orNestedWhere:[sb where:@"wheraCoumnB" equals:@"whereBEqualValue"], [sb where:@"wheraCoumnB" equals:@"sth"], nil];
```

There are two things happening from here on:

- The arguments are evaluated in any order (in which order is not
  specified in C standard and it changes between compilers and
  settings)
- Eventhough this should be obvious to every programmer: The inner
  functions are evaluated before

Now I want to know for example inside this method call...

```
 [sb where:@"wheraCoumnB" equals:@"whereBEqualValue"]
```

.. that it was called as part of an argument of a function.

Possible? Black magic?

Before you come and say I'm doing it wrong, and I should fix my code: I claim that I have one of the rare cases where it will make sense to know such thing. I'm writing a query builder, and this would greatly ease the use of nested conditions. Otherwise I'd have to do some silly nestedAndBegin and later nestedAndEnd in order to implement brackets, and so on. It would be awkward in this case, my query builder is tree based and I would not like to do this (unlike the string juggling query builders all that would be required is putting the node for the logical expression in place).

**Update**

So this is unsurprisingly not possible. For those who are interested how I worked around this for my particular problem: I've made it so all calls to functions are deferred, so the calls to a function of my query builder puts a method invocation object with function arguments to an invocation list. It doesn't execute any method code at that time. 
Each invocation object has an auto-inc sequence Id, so I know when a function has been evaluated. Now in the nestedAnd etc functions (so those functions that my question was about) I check if the sequence Id of the stored invocation objects correspond to the argument index of the function call. If not, this is the right time to reorder them.

The syntax check and query building phase is then deferred until a user actually calls the query() method (or ast() to get the expression tree).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no (practical) way to do that.

You could, theoretically, add some code in your method that reads the debugging symbols from your binary, inspects the link register, and then uses that information to figure out the call site, loads up the source code from somewhere else, and figures out the mapping, parses the source code and figures out it's being called as you describe.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer, but maybe someone knows of a feasible workaround. I'd otherwise probably add some kind of transaction log, which would reverse the last changes by the inner functions and reapply them in correct order at the time the outer function is called. But unfortunately this would mean to break with some possibilities of validation for the query construction.

Comment: You can pass selectors and arguments around, too.

Comment: ha, maybe that's it. I could, instead of construction the tree directly, collect all (copies) of arguments and selectors. and apply them in correct order when the query string is requested (including syntax check, though at a later point)

Comment: That sounds possible, yes.